# Thinkpad unable to boot into Fedora after shutting down during update

Tags: boot, grub2, bios, firmware, thinkpad

I have have a Thinkpad L13 yoga gen 3 (Amd) which I bought to use Fedora on and has mostly been a good experience.

Recently I installed a firmware update through Gnome software which was unusual since it took a considerable amount of time (30+ minutes) and caused the fans to ramp up a lot. I had never experienced this before updating the firmware on this device and at this point the device was just displaying the Lenovo splash screen and the progress bar had completed and disappeared. I know this was stupid but I powered off the system by holding down the power button. Turning the device on everything seemed to work fine except when booting into fedora it would get stuck on a blank screen with a dash on the top left.

- I've tried editing the boot entry params for any information but nothing came up except for a new message "booting from command list".
- I also reset the bios to the defaults but all that's done is make it come up with a large blue box (I think from Linux not the bios) and then restarted the system. This never came up again and I couldn't get a good look at what it said before it restarted.
- I tried booting into a live system from a USB as well but that also had the same problem.

I can get into grub but not anything further and when the system is on it gets incredibly hot.

I've been looking online for solutions but I can't seem to find any. Does anyone know how I might fix this? I think I should reinstall the firmware but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that. Sorry if this isn't the right place to ask. Any help would be appreciated.

The current bios version is "R1TET37W (1.16)" if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more looking around, it turns out that this was caused by the firmware update itself and seems to effect the gen 3 L series of laptops as others with L series thinkpads have reported having this issue after updating as well.

I fixed it by downgrading to version 1.14. It also seems like Lenovo no longer has the 1.16 update available on their site, although I can't confirm this since I didn't initially download the update from there.

Official firmware downloads can be found here by selecting the product or inputting its serial number and selecting "BIOS/UEFI" from the "drivers and software" tab:
https://pcsupport.lenovo.com